# DNS zones and named files

Tags: windows-server-2003, domain-name-system, bind

I've installed BIND in my Windows server2003. i've configured the named file in C:\named\etc\named.conf as:

options {
directory "c:\named\zones";
allow-transfer { none; };
recursion no;
};

zone "tisdns.com" IN {
type master;
file "db.tisdns.com.txt";
allow-transfer { none; };
};

My zone file is configured in C:\named\zones\db.tisdns.com.txt as:
$TTL 6h
@ IN SOA ns1.tisdns.com. hostmaster.tisdns.co… (
2010010901
10800
3600
604800
86400 )

@ NS ns1.tisdns.com.

ns1 IN A 192.168.0.17
mug IN A 192.168.0.103

key "rndc-key" {
algorithm hmac-md5;
secret "M0oW24WFQZhMu9wTq8qepw==";
};

controls {
inet 127.0.0.1 port 53
allow { 127.0.0.1; } keys { "rndc-key"; };
};

In the above i've given the name to the  domain as "tisdns". i want to create a new domain name in a different zone file. how can i create it?

Answer (score 2):

Just create a new file in the same folder (C:\named\zones) and add another zone entry in the named conf file for it:

```
zone "tisdns.com" IN { type master; file "db.tisdns.com.txt"; allow-transfer { none; }; };
zone "another.com" IN { type master; file "db.another.com.txt"; allow-transfer { none; }; };
```